# How do I install scipy, numpy and scikit-learn on snow leopard?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, osx-snow-leopard, scikit-learn

I have been trying to install scipy, numpy and scikit-learn on snow leopard with python 2.7 but without success so far.

All I can find is for Lion which I can't upgrade to. I successfully installed python 2.7, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper and numpy. But when I tried to install scipy I got this error.

```
/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-//cc3jPxg5.s:3149:junk `@GOTPCREL' after expression

/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-//cc3jPxg5.s:3149:`___dso_handle@GOTPCREL(%rip)' is not a valid base/index expression

/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-//cc3jPxg5.s:3150:`__ZStL8__ioinit(%rip)' is not a valid base/index expression

/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-//cc3jPxg5.s:3151:junk `@GOTPCREL' after expression

/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-//cc3jPxg5.s:3151:`__ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev@GOTPCREL(%rip)' is not a valid base/index expression

/var/folders/KU/KUY52WxPExK-Pljd3M-eV++++TM/-Tmp-//cc3jPxg5.s:3155:bad register name `%rsp'


error: Command "c++ -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -Iscipy/interpolate/src -I/Users/user/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c scipy/interpolate/src/_interpolate.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/scipy/interpolate/src/_interpolate.o" failed with exit status 1
```

I have gcc and g++ 4.2 installed and I think I have found out that it should be for gcc, g++ 4.0 which I don't know how to install.

What should I do to successfully intall scipy, numpy and scikit-learn on Snow Leopard?

Thanks very much.

EDIT: I use `brew install python` to install python 2.7.3 and I have Xcode 4.2 installed on my snow leopard. And the above is the error I got when I was trying to install scipy.

And when I look into my /usr/bin I only have 

`g++, g++-4.2`

g++ is also version 4.2.1

Comment: First, which Python 2.7 did you install, which g++ 4.2 did you install, and how are you trying to install `scipy`? In particular, are you using the python.org 2.7, and the command line tools (or Unix dev tools or whatever they were called) from the last 10.6-compatible Xcode, or are you, e.g., mixing up MacPorts g++ with Homebrew Python? Please give the exact steps you went through to get where you are. Most importantly, what is the actual c++ error message that led to the exit status 1?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you've installed Xcode 3.x and its command line tools, you already have `g++-4.0` as well as `g++-4.2`, and they're available in /usr/bin, so if you actually follow the steps on http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Mac_OS_X it should work. Finally, have you considered using, e.g., ActiveState, Enthought, xy, etc.? If you need to do scientific computing and aren't (and don't want to become) an expert on setting up a complicated dev environment, you are their exact target market.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question already. I installed python from brew. and I have Xcode 4.2 installed on my mac. What I really want is just scikit-learn and it requires scipy and numpy. So, if I install ActiveState, Enthought will it work as well?

Comment: A bunch of comments: First, even Homebrew recommends not using Homebrew Python 2.x. If you can't use one of the built-in Apple versions (IIRC, 10.6 only came with 2.5 and 2.6, so if you need 2.7, this means you), I'd either use python.org (if I want to install packages explicitly) or ActiveState or Enthought (if I want as much as possible pre-installed). Second, it sounds like SciPy expects a /usr/bin/g++-4.0 if you're on 10.6. If Xcode 4 doesn't give you that (you did install the Command Line Tools, right?), you may need Xcode 3 instead/as well.

Comment: Thanks abamert I installed XCode 4 that I downloaded from Apple website before they deleted from the site when they released Lion. I'll try to install python again from scratch.

Comment: All they took down was the simple Xcode download page (because you're now supposed to use the App Store if you just want the latest version). You can still download all the older versions in the Mac Dev Center; go to developer.apple.com, sign in, and click "Other Downloads". I believe "Xcode 3.2.6 and iOS SDK 4.3 for Snow Leopard" is the last version with g++ 4.0, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have Xcode 4.2 installed too, but managed to found a gcc-4.0 on my system that worked. Not sure how it got there, but I suppose it came with Xcode 4.2.

So, before installing an older version of Xcode you may want to check if you have a gcc-4.0 in this location:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/
```

All I did was to run this:

```
export CC=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.0
export CXX=/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.0
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
```

... before installing scipy:

```
pip install scipy
```